# Unable to connect to RabbitMq via SSL

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have a problem while trying to connect to RabbitMQ server via SSL.
If i try to execute without SSL there's no problem. But unfortunately when I try to connect via SSL I get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://localhost:5671 (Unknown error) in /var/www/html/rabbitmq/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:110
```

**Software versions**

```
RabbitMQ 3.8.9
Erlang 23.1.4
```

**RabbitMQ listeners**

```
Interface: [::], port: 15672, protocol: http, purpose: HTTP API
Interface: [::], port: 25672, protocol: clustering, purpose: inter-node and CLI tool communication
Interface: [::], port: 5672, protocol: amqp, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0
Interface: [::], port: 5671, protocol: amqp/ssl, purpose: AMQP 0-9-1 and AMQP 1.0 over TLS
```

**rabbitmq.config**

```
[
  {rabbit, [
     {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
     {auth_mechanisms, ['EXTERNAL','PLAIN','AMQPLAIN']},
     {ssl_options, [{cacertfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/ssl2/result/ca_certificate.pem"},
                    {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/ssl2/result/server_certificate.pem"},
                    {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/ssl2/result/server_key.pem"},
                    {verify,verify_none},
                    {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}]}
   ]}
].
```

**AMQP connection options**

```
$ssl_opts = ['ssl_version' => 'tlsv1.2','verify_peer' => false];
$connection = new AMQPSSLConnection('localhost', 5671, 'user', 'password', 'vhost', $ssl_opts);
```

**openssl test**

```
openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:5671 -cert client_certificate.pem -key client_key.pem -CAfile ca_certificate.pem  -tls1_2 -cipher ALL

CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 282 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1606214149
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

Comment: It's working. Stupid mistake. Wrong permissions to `/etc/rabbitmq/ssl` directory.

Comment: For me the issue was nowhere did I find any documentation that you may need to have a greater depth in your advanced.config file. e.g.
```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, []},
    {ssl_listeners, [5671]},
    {ssl_options, [
      {cacertfile, "cacertfile.pem"},
      {certfile, "certfile.pem"},
      {keyfile, "cert_key.pem"},
      {verify, verify_peer},
      {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true},
      {depth, 8}
    ]
    }
  ]}
].
```